# How was The Pirate Bay able to get back online after being shut down?

Tags: united-states, copyright, intellectual-property, online-piracy, sweden

The Pirate Bay in the past year had its servers raided by Swedish Police and the site was shut down. On what grounds were Swedish police able to raid TPB servers and shut down the site, under Swedish Law? And how was TPB, under Swedish law, able to reclaim its servers and control of thepiratebay.se domain name?

Comment: Whether they're able to physically move their hands and type things into computers to get the site set up to resume access has nothing to do with whether that's legal or not.

Comment: Yes, I read your question. Your question assumes incorrectly that because they were physically able to get the site running, that means they were legally allowed to get the site running. Your new additions assume that they are a religion, which they're not, and that that has something to do with the legality.

Comment: For the religion, see the Wikipedia article on the [Missionary Church of Kopimism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missionary_Church_of_Kopimism), which specifically states "[The founder of the church] has denied any connection between the Church and filesharing site The Pirate Bay." It also says "The religion's association with illegal file sharing has been said not to be a sign that illegal file-sharing will be excused from Sweden's zero-tolerance approach to the controversial matter."

Comment: @Dawn I made it more clear for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at the Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pirate_Bay you can read that

> In some countries, Internet service providers have been ordered to
>   block access to the website. **Subsequently, proxies have been providing
>   access to it, and its content is being provided by multiple
>   round-robin servers, collectively nicknamed the "TPB hydra."**

That page has about all the info you need about how they operate, their legal situation (in particular the May 2006 raid) and more. The Wikipedia page is continuously updated: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=The_Pirate_Bay&action=history

Also, read TPB's own usage policy and disclaimer: https://thepiratebay.se/policy  which includes the line:

> The responsibility lies upon the user to not spread malicious, false
>   or illegal material using the site.

**Update 8/16/2017**: The Pirate Bay is back at the URL `thepiratebay.org` while the domain `thepiratebay.se` is now forwarded to it.